# Firefox Addon - Change address bar url when domain matches some pattern

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to know how to change the `address bar url` when `domain` matches some `pattern`?. The url have to change after the url be loaded. I have tryed the following code. It works, but some times it doesn't. Maybe depending on the load speed, i don't know. What I mean is that this code is not too consistent. I think it could be enhanced. Maybe using an `observer` with: `http-on-examine-response` some how?. I'm looking for a consistent code.

```
var {getMostRecentBrowserWindow} = require("sdk/window/utils");
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");

var domain = "yahoo.com";
var display_url = "http://www.mybeautifulemail.com"

function change_addressbar_url(url) {
    var ioService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
    var uri = ioService.newURI(url, null, null);
    var win = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    win.gBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI(uri);
}

var win = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
win.gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var url_regexp = new RegExp(escape_regexp(domain)+"$", "i");
    if (this.currentURI.host.match(url_regexp))
        change_addressbar_url(display_url);
}, false);

function escape_regexp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Thank you very much!

**[CODE REVISION 001]**

```
var {getMostRecentBrowserWindow} = require("sdk/window/utils");
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");

var domain = "yahoo.com";
var display_url = "http://www.mybeautifulemail.com"

function escape_regexp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function change_addressbar_url(url, tab) {
    var ioService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
    var uri = ioService.newURI(url, null, null);
    tab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI(uri);
}

var win = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
win.gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
    var contWin = e.target;
    if (contWin.top) {
        return; // this is a frame load so ignore it
    }
    var contDoc = contWin.document;
    var DOMWin = contWin.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                    .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
                    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                    .rootTreeItem
                    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                    .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);

    console.log("... CODE NEVER ARRIVES THIS POINT");

    var gBrowser = DOMWin.gBrowser;
    var tab = gBrowser._getTabForContentWindow(contWin);
    var url_regexp = new RegExp(escape_regexp(domain) + "$", "i");
    if (tab.linkedBrowser.currentURI.host.match(url_regexp)) {
        change_addressbar_url(display_url, tab);
        console.log("... host matched pattern!");
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: I suspect that faking URLs would run afoul of AMO's code review guidelines since the URL bar is security-relevant.

Comment: but actually the code works as I want, maybe in a 70% of the cases. So since there is a way to do it I think it is not a big problem to do it. My problem is that the code doesn't work at 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the line `win.gBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI` AND also the `if (this.currentURI.host.match(url_regexp))` these lines work on the currently selected tab in that window. what you need to do is get the correct tab element then set the uri on that tab so like this: `win.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNode[0].linkedBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI` would set the address bar in tab 1 as notice the `.childNode[0]`

So this is how you get the right tab:

```
var win = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
win.gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
    var contWin = e.originalTarget.defaultView;
    if (contWin.fameElement) {
        // this is a frame load so ignore it
        return;
    }
    var contDoc = contWin.document;
    var DOMWin = contWin.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                    .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
                    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                    .rootTreeItem
                    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                    .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
    var gBrowser = DOMWin.gBrowser;

    var tab = gBrowser._getTabForContentWindow(contWin);
    var url_regexp = new RegExp(escape_regexp(domain)+"$", "i");
    if (tab.linkedBrowser.currentURI.host.match(url_regexp))
        change_addressbar_url(display_url, tab);
}, false);

function change_addressbar_url(url, tab) {
    var ioService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
    var uri = ioService.newURI(url, null, null);
    tab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI(uri);
}
```

Comment: I got "ReferenceError: gBrowser is not defined". The error is on the line: var tab = gBrowser._getTabForContentWindow(contWin);

Comment: The code doesn't work. I did the change and published it as: "[CODE REVISION 001]" on my question above. The execution never arrives to the line: "console.log("... CODE NEVER ARRIVES THIS POINT");".

Comment: i edited it, you caught an early inital version. where i was using `contWin.top` to test if its frame instead of `contWin.frameElement`. copy paste the latest code snippet and try that out

Comment: cool man :) you also are just adding the listener to the most recent open window. you need to add to all current open windows and then set up to attach to future opened windows. you know that right? for that you would use this boiler plate: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/1c7ab2c49c7640ff84db

Comment: I don't unerstand too much what you say. Could you say me in what cases the algorithm above will fail?, maybe one step by step guide?, for example: 1- open a firefox window ..., 2- open new tab, 3- go to the url ..., 4- submit the info ...,etc. Thank you @Notidart

Comment: ups, I did a try now again, and I had the same problem as initially. I think that before when it worked was inside the 70% of correct behaviour I mentioned on a comment before, so I'm in the same situation :(

Comment: 1) if you run your script you have to have a window with tabs open otherwise it will fail. 2) if you run your script while a window with tabs is open it attaches to that one window. 3) if you had two windows with tabs and run your code it will only attach to the most recent one. 4) if you open new windows with tabs it will not work in those new windows (what i mean by with tabs is if it has a gBrowser, so a `navigator:browser` type window). this is due to your lines here: `var win = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
win.gBrowser.addEventListener`

Comment: In other words you are attaching to only the most recent `navigator:browser` type window. See this code on how to use the window attach boilerplate so it gets all windows: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9406437#file-bootstrap-js-L83

Comment: thank you very much @Notidart. I will check this in the future because now I'm with other things but I think you have explained all this very well and in the future if I need it (or other users does) I will be well driven if I face the same problem, so I mark this thread as solved. Thank you! :)

Comment: @nightclub i'll stick this into that boilerplate for you later today, it takes like 10minutes.